# Quiero leer rows desde una base de datos con EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Cuando quiero usar el metodo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Students.ToListAsync());
}
```

El metodo `ToListAsync` no me sale y me da un error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Deberias aclarar que error te sale...

Comment: No es un error, si no, ves la linea roja  que sale cuando estas llamando un metodo que no existe dentro de una clase, que se le pone la linea roja debajo, eso es como si ese metodo no existiera en el context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo extensor que buscas esta en la clase [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions) que pertence al `namespace` [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore) por lo que tienes que agregar el using:

```
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: gracias eso mismo era